# How to access on lockscreen keypad when home button is locked

Tags: android

I have a lockscreen with edittext for a password. I have disabled my home button of phone unless user enters the correct password. But as I have locked home button, I am unable to access qwerty keyboard to let user enter the password.

Can anyone please help me to access that keyboard, even if the home button is locked?

I have used the class HomeKeyLocker to lock home button

```
package com.etkin.securityapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 4/22/2016.
 */
public class HomeKeyLocker
{
private OverlayDialog mOverlayDialog;

public void lock(Activity activity)
{
    if (mOverlayDialog == null)
    {
        mOverlayDialog = new OverlayDialog(activity);
        mOverlayDialog.show();
    }
}

public void unlock() {
    if (mOverlayDialog != null) {
        mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
        mOverlayDialog = null;
    }
}

private static class OverlayDialog extends AlertDialog {

    public OverlayDialog(Activity activity)
    {
        super(activity, R.style.OverlayDialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.type = TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        params.dimAmount = 0.0F; // transparent
        params.width = 0;
        params.height = 0;
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL ,         0xffffff);
        setOwnerActivity(activity);
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    public final boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionevent) {
        return true;
    }

    protected final void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
        framelayout.setBackgroundColor(0);
        setContentView(framelayout);
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: how did you lock the home button?  We need to see some code to answer.

Comment: i have used a custom HomeKeyLocker class to lock home button and back button

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: the class HomekeyLocker is mentioned above in the question itself. I have simply made object of this class and used its lock and unlock methods in lockscreen activity.